# Почему в этом случае не работает простой возврат функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Создать функцию, которая будет принимать и функцию и список значений и возвращать список, в котором каждое значение будет результатом применения к нему переданной функции.

Пример:

```
def inc(a):
    return a + 1


f_map(inc, [1, 2, 3]) == [2, 3, 4]
f_map(inc, []) == []
```

наш код:

```
def f_map(func, l):
    return func(l)
```

Comment: Вы применяете func к списку, а не к каждому значению из списка

Comment: спасибо, всё получилось!!!

Comment: @iwannabeadog, оформите, пожалуйста, ответом :)

Answer (score 0):

```
def f_map(func, l):
    return [func(i) for i in l]
```